# Export Data From Merged File to Individual

Tags: export, qgis-processing, expression, batch

I Have a merged shape file with 'n' number of cities in it. Exporting them by selecting their names individually is a difficult thing and wasting my time.

Is their any query in QGIS to export Data from Merged file to Multiple According to their Names?

[image]

Comment: You don't seem to be using GeoTools so I've removed the tag you had for that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want every feature in a new file, you can simply use the `Save Vector Features To File` processing algorithm and use the `Iterate` option.
You'll get a new file for each feature.

[image]